# Can't get PHP to write path to file on MySQL update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that uploads an image to my server and stores the path to the image in MySQL and the form works perfect.
What I am wanting to do now is be able to update the stored image and path stored in MySQL but I can't figure out how to add the $target variable to my code so it updates the path and file name in MySQL.
The way I have the code now it will upload the new image but wont update the path and name in MySQL, I know it has something to do with the $target I just don't know where to put it.
And yes I am well aware of sql injection so please no need to comment on it as I don't care about it for this scenario.

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be uploaded and saved
$target = "uploads/cheer/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']);

//This gets all the form data//
//----------MEMBER INFO----------//
$team_name=$_POST['team_name'];
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$registration=$_POST['registration'];
$pay_status=$_POST['pay_status'];
$physical=$_POST['physical'];
$photo=$_POST['photo'];
$logo_src=$_POST['logo_src'];
//----------NOTES----------//
$notes=$_POST['notes'];
//----------IMAGES----------//
$pic=($_FILES['member_photo']['name']);

//----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
include 'elite_connect.php';

//----------WRITES DATA TO DATABASE----------//
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes', member_photo='$member_photo', 
WHERE `id` = '$id'");
//----------DISPLAYS MYSQL ERRORS----------//
print_r($_POST);
echo mysql_error();
//----------WRITES PHOTO TO SERVER----------//
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['member_photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
//----------TELLS IF ALL IS OK----------//
echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']). "has been uploaded!";
}
else {
//----------GIVES AN ERROR IF IT'S NOT----------//
?><br/><?php
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image.";
}
?>
```

Adding $target to SET  produces the following error from the process_edit.php file

> Array ( [id] => 18 [first_name] => Your [last_name] => Daddy [team_name] => [registration] => YES [pay_status] => PENDING [physical] => NO [photo] => [notes] => I\'m your daddy [logo_src] => logos/cougars2013.jpg [submit] => Update Member ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''uploads/cheer/helmet1.jpg' WHERE `id` = ''' at line 1The file helmet1.jpghas been uploaded!

as you can see the updates are being written to MySQL and the image is uploaded to the server but the path to the image is not updated.

so echoing the entire query pretty much gives the exact same thing as above,

> Array ( [id] => 20 [first_name] => Fat [last_name] => Amy [team_name] => [registration] => YES [pay_status] => PAID IN FULL [physical] => YES [photo] => YES [notes] => Large and in Charge! [logo_src] => logos/gvklogo2013.png [submit] => Update Member ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uploads/images/fatamy.png='uploads/images/fatamy.png' WHERE `id` = '20'' at line 12 The file fatamy.png has been uploaded!

In case this helps, here is the code that processes the input form to upload the file and store the path.

```
    <?php

//This is the directory where images will be uploaded and saved
$target = "uploads/cheer/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']);

//This gets all the form data//
//----------MEMBER INFO----------//
$team_name=$_POST['team_name'];
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$registration=$_POST['registration'];
$pay_status=$_POST['pay_status'];
$physical=$_POST['physical'];
$photo=$_POST['photo'];
$logo_src=$_POST['logo_src'];
//----------NOTES----------//
$notes=$_POST['notes'];
//----------IMAGES----------//
$pic=($_FILES['member_photo']['name']);

//----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
include 'elite_connect.php';

//----------WRITES DATA TO DATABASE----------//
mysql_query("INSERT INTO cheer (team_name, first_name, last_name, registration, pay_status, physical, photo, logo_src, notes, member_photo)
VALUES ('$team_name','$first_name','$last_name','$registration','$pay_status','$physical','$photo','$logo_src','$notes','$target')");
//----------DISPLAYS MYSQL ERRORS----------//
echo mysql_error();
//----------WRITES PHOTO TO SERVER----------//
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['member_photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
//----------TELLS IF ALL IS OK----------//
echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']). "has been uploaded!";
}
else {
//----------GIVES AN ERROR IF IT'S NOT----------//
?><br/><?php
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image.";
}
?>
```

I may as well add the update form as well

```
            <tr class="firstname">
                        <td class="firstname" style="width: 58px">First Name</td>
                        <td class="firstname" style="width: 280px">

                        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $data2['first_name']?>" style="width: 170px"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lastname">
                        <td class="label" style="width: 58px">Last Name</td>
                        <td class="field" style="width: 280px">

                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $data2['last_name']?>" style="width: 171px">
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr class="teamname">
                        <td class="teamname" style="width: 58px">Team Name</td>
                        <td class="teamname" style="width: 280px">

                        <input type="text"  name="team_name" id="teamname" value="<?php echo $data2['team_name']?>" style="width: 170px">
                        <br>
            </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="typeName">
                    <td class="label" style="width: 58px">Registration</td>
                    <td class="field" style="width: 280px">
                    <input type="text" name="registration" id="jerseybrand" value="<?php echo $data2['registration']?>" style="width: 170px">                       
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="paystatus">
                    <td class="paystatus" style="width: 58px">Payment Status</td>
                    <td class="paystatus" style="width: 280px">
                    <input type="text" name="pay_status" id="paystatus" value="<?php echo $data2['pay_status']?>" style="width: 170px">
                    <br>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="physical">
                    <td class="physical" style="width: 58px">Physical</td>
                    <td class="physical" style="width: 290px">
                    <input type="text" name="physical" id="physical" value="<?php echo $data2['physical']?>">
                    </tr style="width: 170px">
                    <tr class="photo">
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 58px">Photo Taken</td>
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 290px">
                    <input type="text" name="photo" id="photo" value="<?php echo $data2['photo']?>">
                    </tr style="width: 170px">

                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    Notes
                    </td>
                    <td class="notes" style="width: 280px">
                    <textarea name="notes" id="notes" class="auto-style1" style="height: 35px; width: 215px"><?php echo $data2['notes']?></textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr class="teamlogo">
                    <td class="teamlogo" style="width: 58px">Team Logo</td>
                    <td class="teamlogo" style="width: 280px">
                    <img name="logo_image "src="<?php echo $data2['logo_src']?>" id="logoimage" height="100" width="100">
                    </td width="116">

                    <input type="hidden" name="logo_src" value="<?php echo $data2['logo_src']?>" id="logosrc"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="logosrc">
                        <td class="logosrc" style="width: 58px">Change Logo</td>
                        <td class="logosrc" style="width: 280px">

                        <select name="team_name" id="dd" onChange="swapImage()" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="" title="logos/cheerlogoleft.jpg">SELECT</option>
    <option value="COUGARS" title="logos/cougars2013.jpg" >Cougars</option>
    <option value="FALCONS" title="logos/falcons2013.jpg" >Falcons</option>
    <option value="GREEN VALLEY KNIGHTS" title="logos/gvklogo2013.png">Green Valley Knights</option>
    <option value="LONGHORNS" title="logos/longhorns2013.jpg">Longhorns</option>
    <option value="MUSTANGS" title="logos/mustangs2013.jpg">Mustangs</option>
        <option value="NW NINERS" title="logos/nwniners2013.jpg">NW Niners</option>
        <option value="REBELS" title="logos/rebels2013.jpg">Rebels</option>
        <option value="WILDCATS" title="logos/wildcats2013.jpg">Wildcats</option>
</select>

</td> 
                    </tr>
<tr class="photo">
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 58px">Change Photo</td>
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 290px">
                    <input type="file" name="member_photo" id="cheerphoto"/>
                    </tr style="width: 170px">

            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

    </td><td id="righttdhw" style="width: 517px; height: 141px;">
        <fieldset id="info" style="width: 260px; height: 183px">

        <legend id="infoLegend">Member Photo</legend>

        <div id="memberphoto"> 
        <table style="height: 156px; width: 260px;">
        <tbody>
                <tr class="memberphoto">
                   <td class="field" style="width: 269px; height: 132px; text-align: center;">
                    <img name="member_photo" src="<?php echo $data2['member_photo']?>" id="memberphoto" height="150" width="250" >

                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Comment: 1. Plz, don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. 2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @user4035 He sai in this case SQL injection isn't a problem.

Comment: @Sean Yes, see it now. Kind of a reflex.

Comment: @user4035 Unless someone is going to come into my office and take my laptop from me and log into this form I could care less about sql injection.

Comment: `so it updates the path and file name in MySQL` Well... how are they stored in the first place?

Comment: @user2447848 You don't have $target variable anywhere in your SQL request. Why aren't you saving it?

Comment: @sean the original input form selects the image to be uploaded and it's processed by code similar to above except using INSERT obviously but I am able to put $target in the values, with UPDATE I can't figure out how to use $target so the image is uploaded but the path associated with $target = $target "uploads/cheer/" isn't changed

Comment: well... how about `mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', ..., target='$target' 
WHERE id = '$id'");`?

Comment: @Sean that's the first thing I tried and it didn't work, gave my an error telling me to check my sql at that line.

Comment: well... try giving us the full error - so we can see the constructed query and maybe see the problem

Comment: @Sean here is what I get when I add just the $target to the SET statement  Array ( [id] => 18 [first_name] => Your [last_name] => Daddy [team_name] => [registration] => YES [pay_status] => PENDING [physical] => NO [photo] => [notes] => I\'m your daddy [logo_src] => logos/cougars2013.jpg [submit] => Update Member ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''uploads/cheer/helmet1.jpg' WHERE `id` = ''' at line 1The file helmet1.jpghas been uploaded!  you can see it uploads the image just no path update

Comment: hmmm... need to see the full query... `echo` the full query before running it, so we can see the whole thing - the error is probably caused by what is just before what the error shows us :)

Comment: @sean not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma in your query before the `WHERE` that shouldn't be there. The query won't complete with the comma and hence there is no update!

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes', member_photo='$member_photo', WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

**UPDATE**

You need to set a value for `$id` before you can use it in your query: `$id = $_POST[id]`

Then run the query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes', member_photo='$target'  WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

Comment: that was a typo, I had $target after that and forgot to remove the comma when I deleted $target. That comma isn't in the code on the server. As I said all the data will update except for the file path to the image. I don't get any errors just not update to the image path.

Comment: Okay, what fields are in the table? and what fields are you trying to update?

Comment: everything listed above is in the form and I am updating any changes to those fields. Like I said everything else updates just not the path to the image because I don't know how to add the $target variable

Comment: Using the query that has everything in (and is producing the error shown in the comments above) can you echo the produced output? So instead of `mysql_query("UPDATE .....");` you put `echo "UPDATE .....";` and then paste the actual query that is being sent to MySQL so I can see it?

Comment: ok done pretty much shows the same thing, I used the next entry up just to make sure only difference is this time it shows the id number in the update. I posted it up top

Comment: Nope, that isn't done! There shouldn't be a mysql error because you're not running the query!!! The echo should read something like: `UPDATE table SET field1 = 'value1' WHERE id = 1` -- Just with your field/table names etc

Comment: I tried to use member_photo='$target' in the SET statement which removes the sql error but still doesn't write the path in MySQL

Comment: Can you also copy/paste everything that you write inside of `mysql_query`?

Comment: it's already in the original post up top mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes', member_photo='$member_photo', 
WHERE `id` = '$id'");

Comment: except now I have it like this  mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes', member_photo='$target', 
WHERE `id` = '$id'");

Comment: Ahh sorry, I understand... Try: `UPDATE cheer SET member_photo='test' WHERE id = 1` that should update the row with `id = 1` (I assume that row exists - if not change the ID) to see if it updates `member_photo`

Comment: I'll correct that statement, for some reason that actually works. but I don't understand why as the id record for all the other data for that record updates

Comment: I got it, I added $id=$_POST['id'] at the top of the page and changed member_photo='$member_photo' to member_photo='$target' and it works

Comment: Thanks for your help Steven, this id part is killing me I left it out on a similar form last night and Sean helped me fix it, you would think that's the first thing I would have thought of but because I saw the record for that id update in MySQL I figured it was passing the id. If you put this solution in an answer I'll accept it for you. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 when I'm debugging my own code it's a glaringly simple problem; but they're the ones we overlook unfortunately! Thank you for accepting the edited answer.

Comment: you're welcome. Having fixed that issue has now created a bigger problem with the image path being deleted from MySQL on the update if nothing is selected for the file upload. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Just whack in an if statement so that if nothing is uploaded it skips or redirects to another page.